# Meteor update access denied despite presence of insecure

Tags: javascript, mongodb, authentication, meteor

I have the insecure package installed and yet I get the following in the client console:

```
Meteor.user()
Object {_id: "4Dyaa5wRmxmq7j7XF", profile: Object, services: Object}_id: "4Dyaa5wRmxmq7j7XF"profile: Objectname: "Mel Oug"__proto__: Objectservices: Objectfacebook: Object__proto__: Object__proto__: Object__defineGetter__: function __defineGetter__() { [native code] }__defineSetter__: function __defineSetter__() { [native code] }__lookupGetter__: function __lookupGetter__() { [native code] }__lookupSetter__: function __lookupSetter__() { [native code] }constructor: function Object() { [native code] }hasOwnProperty: function hasOwnProperty() { [native code] }isPrototypeOf: function isPrototypeOf() { [native code] }propertyIsEnumerable: function propertyIsEnumerable() { [native code] }toLocaleString: function toLocaleString() { [native code] }toString: function toString() { [native code] }valueOf: function valueOf() { [native code] }get __proto__: function __proto__() { [native code] }set __proto__: function __proto__() { [native code] }
va = Meteor.user()._id
"4Dyaa5wRmxmq7j7XF"
Meteor.users.update(va, {$set: {email: 'the@aarts.com'}})
1
debug.js:41 update failed: Access denied
```

I'm not sure what other relevant code to include. I have no deny (or allow) rules set up. It's a pretty straight forward user setup, I just can't see what might block it.

Here's what packages I got:

```
ccounts-facebook          1.0.4  Login service for Facebook accounts
accounts-google            1.0.4  Login service for Google accounts
accounts-twitter           1.0.4  Login service for Twitter accounts
aldeed:autoform            5.1.2  Easily create forms with automatic insert a...
aldeed:collection2         2.3.3  Automatic validation of insert and update o...
autopublish                1.0.3  Publish the entire database to all clients
blaze                      2.1.2  Meteor Reactive Templating library
cmather:handlebars-server  2.0.0  Allows handlebars templates to be defined o...
email                      1.0.6  Send email messages
insecure                   1.0.3  Allow all database writes by default
iron:router                1.0.7  Routing specifically designed for Meteor
meteor-platform            1.2.2  Include a standard set of Meteor packages i...
mquandalle:jade            0.4.1* Jade template language
msavin:mongol              1.0.30* The insanely handy development package for...
service-configuration      1.0.4  Manage the configuration for third-party se...
twbs:bootstrap             3.3.4  The most popular front-end framework for de...
useraccounts:bootstrap     1.8.1* Accounts Templates styled for Twitter Boots
```

Comment: Mongol adds some access/deny rules, maybe try removing it? Or add allow/deny rules, if it will work then some package adds this functionality

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The Meteor.users collection is a special case, with an established structure and permissions. You are only allowed to update the `user.profile` field from the client, even with the insecure package installed.

This will work, for example:

```
Meteor.users.update(va, {$set: {'profile.email': 'the@aarts.com'}})
```

Emails in general are saved from server code and pushed to the provided 'emails' array in the user record.

"emails" : [
        {
            "address" : "the@aarts.com",
            "verified" : false
        }
    ],

From the meteor docs:

> Users are by default allowed to specify their own profile field with Accounts.createUser and modify it with Meteor.users.update. To allow users to edit additional fields, use Meteor.users.allow.